# AKKA actor Stop and the pending messages in the mail box

Tags: akka

Based on my usecase, once the required message comes in, the actor should be stopped. There may be pending messages in the mail box which should be deleted. Wondering if calling stop on the actor is enough?

Thanks,
cabear

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html):

> **Stopping Actors**
>
> Actors are stopped by invoking the stop method of a ActorRefFactory, i.e. ActorContext or ActorSystem. Typically the context is used for stopping child actors and the system for stopping top level actors. The actual termination of the actor is performed asynchronously, i.e. stop may return before the actor is stopped.
>
> Processing of the current message, if any, will continue before the actor is stopped, but additional messages in the mailbox will not be processed. By default these messages are sent to the deadLetters of the ActorSystem, but that depends on the mailbox implementation.

So calling `stop` on the actor *is enough*: pending messages in the mailbox will not be processed.

Comment: Thanks.. is it OK to call stop on the actor from the onMessage of the actor?

Comment: Yes it is perfectly fine.